# sharepoint 2010 edit tab missing from ribbon

Tags: 2010, site-level-ribbon

I am using SharePoint 2010 site with a simple list form, everything was working fine until I update the form (changed a drop-down field to a textbox field).

Now whenever the user starts a new list item then only the ribbon browse tab is visible but the edit mode with save and cancel buttons are missing.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: For all the pages edit mode are hidden/missing **or else** only for a particular site page.

Comment: It was there previously, as its missing users can no longer save the new list entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok not not a complete solution but as all I required from the edit tab was save and cancel I decided to just add individual save and cancel buttons to the form.

So I'm a bit miffed at why I lost the tab but got the desired functionality with the custom buttons.

Answer (score 0):

*May be the solution is very simple*, someone had edited the page and added a content editor web part without adding text. We didn't see this web part and thought there was something gone wrong but now we know it was our own fault :)